# Regenerate source from Antlr4 ParseTree preserving whitespaces

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am able to use Java.g4 grammar and generate lexers and parsers. This grammar is used to get started. I have a *ParseTree* and I walk it and change whatever I want and write it back to a Java source code file. The ParseTree is not directly changed though.

So for example this is the code. But I also modify method names and add annotations to methods. In some cases I also remove method parameters

```
    @Override
    public void enterClassDeclaration(JavaParser.ClassDeclarationContext ctx) {
        printer.write( intervals );
        printer.writeList(importFilter );
        ParseTree pt = ctx.getChild(1);
        /*
            The class name is changed by a visitor because
            we get a ParseTree back
         */
        pt.accept(new ParseTreeVisitor<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object visitChildren(RuleNode ruleNode) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object visitErrorNode(ErrorNode errorNode) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object visit(ParseTree parseTree) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object visitTerminal(TerminalNode terminalNode) {
                String className = terminalNode.getText();
                System.out.println("Name of the class is [ " + className + "]");
                printer.writeText( classModifier.get() + " class " + NEW_CLASS_IDENTIFIER );
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

But I am not sure how to print the changed Java code while preserving all the original whitespaces.

How is that done ?

Update : It seems that the whitespaces and comments are there but not accessible easily. So it looks like I need to specifically keep track of them and write them along with the code. Not sure though.

So more specifically the code is this.

```
          package x;

          import java.util.Enumeration;
          import java.util.*;
```

As I hit the first ImportDeclarationContext I need to store all the hidden space tokens. When I write this code back I want to include those spaces too.

Solution :

**Don't skip but add to a HIDDEN channel**

```
 //
 // Whitespace and comments
 //

 WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
     ;

 COMMENT
     :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
     ;
```

**Use code like this to get them back**

I use this to get the whitespaces and comments before each method. But it should be possible to get whitespaces from other places too. I think.

```
((CommonTokenStream) tokens).getHiddenTokensToLeft( classOrInterfaceModifierContext.getStart().getTokenIndex(),
                                                                Token.HIDDEN_CHANNEL);
```

Comment: Why would you want to modify the parse tree? Sounds more like that you want to generate some kind of output - for this you don't modify the parse three, you just walk it (visitor, or listener) and do what you need to do during.

Comment: 'modify' is the wrong word. I visit and listen.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: your comment seems contradictory; you say you want to modiy the trees in your first sentence.   If you really only *visit* parse tree nodes, why would you need to regenerate source text with the original whitespace?

Comment: I keep seeing people trying to modify ANTLR parse trees and then print them.  That's hard to do.  More details at my SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38245353/120163

Comment: I already read that. I visit and regenerete the source by removing or adding text. I don't modify the tree.